# Setting state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

[Here is sandbox with code](https://helo.com)https://codesandbox.io/s/setting-react-state-mxzkf?file=/src/App.js

We have React state:

```
 const [valid, setValid] = useState({
    nameOK: true,
    nameValidated: false,
    nameError: false,
    emailOk: true,
    emailValidated: false,
    emailError: false
  });
```

An input field and validating function:

```
 function validateName(value) {
    setValid({ ...valid, nameOK: false, nameValidated: true }); //WHY THIS DOES NOT RUN???
    if (value.length > 4) {
      setValid({...valid, nameOK: true, nameError: false});
      
    } else {
      setValid({ ...valid, nameError: true });
    }
  }
```

I would expect to `nameValidated: true` be set unconditionall with every validation,but it does not happen...

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Pascal mentioned you're using the current state and thus overriding your fist change. React does not merge properties in functional component state however. The way to do it is computing new state based on the previous state

```
setValid(valid =>{return { ...valid, property: newValue }});
```

Comment: Same but succinctly: `setValid(valid => ({ ...valid, property: newValue }))`